# Need vbs regex code to remove everything to the left of a word(s)

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have several strings.  Examples:

```
PK - Package
EA -- Each
AB - Solo Container
TB -- Tube
```

I need to get just the text to the right of the last dash.  Sometimes there may be a single dash, sometimes there may be 2 dashes (shouldn't be any more).  So basically, this regex would return:

```
Package
Each
Solo Container
Tube
```

I'm always woefully ignorant when it comes to regex...

**Edit**:
Per karthik manchala's suggestion...

I tried the following:

```
objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "-\s*(\w+)"

strSearchString = _
    "PK - Package"
strNewString = _
    objRegEx.Replace(strSearchString, _
                     "")

MsgBox strNewString
```

and I'm getting the leftmost parts of the strings instead (PK, EA, etc...) 
Am I not using the replace correctly?

**Edit 2:**

Played around a bit more and think I got it figure out.  For anyone that may stumble upon this in the future, the following seems to have done the trick.  Full code:

```
Set objRegEx = _
    CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "^[^-]*-* "

strSearchString = _
    "PK - Package"
strNewString = _
    objRegEx.Replace(strSearchString, _
                     "")

MsgBox strNewString
```

Message box shows "Package" even when there are 2 dashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (.??)$
```

Matches from end to last dash

Also this would work `InstrRev` or `StrReverse` and `Instr`.

```
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    A = Inp.Readline
    Right(A, Len(A) - InstrRev(A, "-"))
Loop
```

Comment: Interesting answer!  I didn't consider reading from the right of the string until I hit a dash.

Comment: I haven't tested RegEx for speed but simple functions must be faster.

Comment: @JackHillard: This is the best answer, I think, since your *EDIT 2* code will not return the substring after the *last* hyphen. Try with `PK - NK - Apple`, and you will see. You should use `^.*-\s*` regex, and do not set `objRegEx.Global = True` (since we only capture once from the beginning of the string) with `objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True` (there are no letters in the regex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
-\s*(\w+)
```

Comment: This seems to return the leftmost part of the string (PK, EA, etc...).  I edited my OP to show the code I'm using with your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This world would be a better place if

(1) People "woefully ignorant" wrt their problem would refrain from resticting the range of possible solutions by asking for specific techniques (RegExp and Replacing in this case) and concentrate on the specs: possible inputs, expected outputs/results. This can be done with skeleton code that tests possible solutions. E.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Function getTail(sInp)
     getTail = "????"
End Function

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      Split("PK - Package|Package", "|") _
    , Split("AB - Solo Container|Solo Container", "|") _
)

Dim aTest
For Each aTest In aTests
    Dim sInp : sInp = aTest(0)
    Dim sExp : sExp = aTest(1)
    Dim sAct : sAct = getTail(sInp)
    WScript.Echo "----", qq(sInp)
    If sAct = sExp Then
       WScript.Echo "ok"
       WScript.Echo "  result:", qq(sAct)
    Else
       WScript.Echo "not ok"
       WScript.Echo "     got:", qq(sAct)
       WScript.Echo "expected:", qq(sExp)
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 30067065-1.vbs
---- "PK - Package"
not ok
     got: "????"
expected: "Package"
---- "AB - Solo Container"
not ok
     got: "????"
expected: "Solo Container"
```

(2) People wouldn't try to answer with untested code. Exploiting the fact that you can re-define a Sub/Function in VBScript, adding

```
' karthik, used as intended (Submatch), fails for "AB - Solo Container|Solo Container"
Function getTail(sInp)
  Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
  r.Pattern = "-\s*(\w+)"
  Dim ms : Set ms = r.Execute(sInp)
  If 1 = ms.Count Then
     getTail = ms(0).SubMatches(0)
  Else
     getTail = "NOT: 1 = ms.Count"
  End If
End Function
```

**after** the first version of getTail(), you get

```
cscript 30067065-1.vbs
---- "PK - Package"
ok
  result: "Package"
---- "AB - Solo Container"
not ok
     got: "Solo"
expected: "Solo Container"
```

You can then easily test an improved pattern `r.Pattern = "-\s*(.+)"`:

```
cscript 30067065-1.vbs
---- "PK - Package"
ok
  result: "Package"
---- "AB - Solo Container"
ok
  result: "Solo Container"
```

To see the flaw in Trigger's RegExp, you can add a further test case

```
Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      Split("PK - Package|Package", "|") _
    , Split("AB - Solo Container|Solo Container", "|") _
    , Split("Just For Trigger - X|X", "|") _
)
```

and a new version of getTail()

```
' Trigger, RegExp
Function getTail(sInp)
  Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
  r.Pattern = "- (.??)$"
  Dim ms : Set ms = r.Execute(sInp)
  If 1 = ms.Count Then
     getTail = ms(0).SubMatches(0)
  Else
     getTail = "NOT: 1 = ms.Count"
  End If
End Function
```

Result:

```
cscript 30067065-1.vbs
---- "PK - Package"
not ok
     got: "NOT: 1 = ms.Count"
expected: "Package"
---- "AB - Solo Container"
not ok
     got: "NOT: 1 = ms.Count"
expected: "Solo Container"
---- "Just For Trigger - X"
ok
  result: "X"
```

"(.??)" looks for zero or **one** character different from \n non-greadily. I just hope that you didn't need test code to see that

```
Right(A, Len(A) - InstrRev(A, "-"))
```

is not valid VBScript. Trigger's InStrRev technique could be used if improved further by Trim():

```
' Trigger, InStrRev improved
Function getTail(sInp)
  getTail = Trim(Right(sInp, Len(sInp) - InstrRev(sInp, "-")))
End Function
```

Another non-RegExp approach uses Split():

```
' using Split
Function getTail(sInp)
  Dim aTmp : aTmp = Split(sInp, "- ")
  getTail = aTmp(UBound(aTmp))
End Function
```

(3) People would think twice before they upvote.